# scaffolding for bootstrap columns in php while loops

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop, scaffolding

I'm trying to present my sql rows in bootstrap grid dynamically

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 4</div>
</div> 
<div class="row>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 5</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 6</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 7</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 8</div>
</div>
```

and I'm having trouble how to set up the while loop. what I have now just does

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 4</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 5</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 6</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 7</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">sql row 8</div>
</div>
```

how can I set up loop to assign four col-md-3 classes to each row automatically and then continue. Current code:

```
<div class="row">
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $spons_amt = round($row["spons_amt"] + 500, 2);
echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . $spons_amt . '</div>'
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
</div>
```

I'm guessing what I need to do is

```
    <div class="row">
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
// count number of rows 
{
//list 4 of these (to make a row)
    $spons_amt = round($row["spons_amt"] + 500, 2);
echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . $spons_amt . '</div>'
} 
// echo </div><div class="row"> between every set of 4
mysqli_close($conn);
</div>
```

Am I going about this the right way? How could I complete the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to use PHP's `array_chunk` function:

```
 foreach(array_chunk($entries, 4) as $entriesRow) {
     echo '<div class="row">';
         foreach ($entriesRow as $entry) {
             echo "<div class='col-md-3'>$entry</div>";
         }
     echo '</div>';
 }
```

(Assuming that you have fetched all DB rows in $entries array.)

Comment: What do the variables equal: $entries (i assume is number of rows), $entries and $entry I'm confused

Comment: $entries are all the rows fetched from database (i.e. with ->fetchAll()). If you pass it as an argument to array_chunk(), with parameter 4, it will return new arrays of size 4. To loop them I named them $entriesRow (each Bootstrap row has 4 entries). Then we need one more foreach to loop each $entriesRow that contains 4 entries. It sounds complicated but is a simple idea. You can check the manual too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$n = 0;
echo '<div class="row">';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $spons_amt = round($row["spons_amt"] + 500, 2);
    if($n%4 == && $n =! 0) { 
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . $spons_amt . '</div>';
        $n = 1;
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . $spons_amt . '</div>';
        $n++;
    }
} 
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: that would echo the first row as empty

Answer (score 0):

No need for all this complexity. Bootstrap works within a 12 col grid system automatically. Just make sure you loop and make col size so that that evenly divides by 12 e.g. col-md-4.

This example will provide 3 per row automatically since 12 / 4 = 3. Just update to use ECHO or whatever you need this is just a basic concept example.

```
<div class="row">
    LOOPCODE
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            DATA
        </div>
    }
</div>
```